# How to refresh call log

Tags: android, calllog

I'm trying to refresh the call log once a button is pressed. I have both a Uri and Cursor defined

```
Cursor c;
Uri allCalls = Uri.parse("content://call_log/calls");
```

and then this function is called in onCreate

```
public void checkLogs() {
    c = getContentResolver().query(allCalls, null, null, null, sOrder);

    while (c.moveToNext()) {
        num = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.NUMBER)); // for
                                                                    // number
        if (num.startsWith("+1")) {
            num = num.substring(2);
        }
        name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NAME)); // for
                                                                            // name
        type = Integer.parseInt(c.getString(c
                .getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.TYPE))); // for type

        if (type == 3 && arrlst.contains(num) == false && name == null) {
            arrlst.add(num);
            initialize(num);
        }

        else {
            arrlst.add(num);
            continue;
        }
    }

    c.close();
}
```

This works, but I tried making a refresh button that contains the following code

```
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case (R.id.menuRefresh):
                allCalls = Uri.parse("content://call_log/calls");
                checkLogs();
    }
    return false;
}
```

when I press the refresh the new calls do not appear, but when I close and open the application they appear. What am I doing wrong?

Error log when trying to use Loader

```
05-25 02:31:14.724: E/AndroidRuntime(18892): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-25 02:31:14.724: E/AndroidRuntime(18892): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.callfinder/com.example.callfinder.FindCalls}: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-25 02:31:14.724: E/AndroidRuntime(18892):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2306)
05-25 02:31:14.724: E/AndroidRuntime(18892):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2356)
05-25 02:31:14.724: E/AndroidRuntime(18892):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:150)
05-25 02:31:14.724: E/AndroidRuntime(18892):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1244)
05-25 02:31:14.724: E/AndroidRuntime(18892):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-25 02:31:14.724: E/AndroidRuntime(18892):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-25 02:31:14.724: E/AndroidRuntime(18892):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5195)
05-25 02:31:14.724: E/AndroidRuntime(18892):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-25 02:31:14.724: E/AndroidRuntime(18892):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-25 02:31:14.724: E/AndroidRuntime(18892):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
05-25 02:31:14.724: E/AndroidRuntime(18892):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:562)
05-25 02:31:14.724: E/AndroidRuntime(18892):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-25 02:31:14.724: E/AndroidRuntime(18892): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-25 02:31:14.724: E/AndroidRuntime(18892):    at com.example.callfinder.FindCalls.checkLogs(FindCalls.java:171)
05-25 02:31:14.724: E/AndroidRuntime(18892):    at com.example.callfinder.FindCalls.onCreate(FindCalls.java:55)
05-25 02:31:14.724: E/AndroidRuntime(18892):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
05-25 02:31:14.724: E/AndroidRuntime(18892):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
05-25 02:31:14.724: E/AndroidRuntime(18892):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2260)
05-25 02:31:14.724: E/AndroidRuntime(18892):    ... 11 more
```

Also the code that I tried to explain if it was confusing in the comment

```
public void initialize() {
    layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ll1);
    tvTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    sOrder = String.format(sDate + " %s", sSort);

    mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.activity_find_calls,
            null, null, null, 0);
    getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);

}

@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int arg0, Bundle arg1) {
    return new CursorLoader(this, allCalls,
            null, null, null, sOrder);
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor cursor) {
    switch (loader.getId()) {
      case 1:
          mAdapter.swapCursor(cursor);
          break;
    }

}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> arg0) {
    mAdapter.swapCursor(null);

}
```

and

```
    public void checkLogs() {
    c = mAdapter.getCursor();
    //c = getContentResolver().query(allCalls, null, null, null, sOrder);

    while (c.moveToNext()) {
        num = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.NUMBER)); // for
                                                                    // number
        if (num.startsWith("+1")) {
            num = num.substring(2);
        }
        name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NAME)); // for
                                                                            // name
        type = Integer.parseInt(c.getString(c
                .getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.TYPE))); // for type

        if (type == 3 && arrlst.contains(num) == false && name == null) {
            arrlst.add(num);
            makeButton(num);
        }

        else {
            arrlst.add(num);
            continue;
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: have you updated your list with the ew cursor??

Comment: Wouldn't calling the function with the cursor (c) update it?

Comment: sorry didn't understand. please post full code of checklog

Comment: and where are you setting the adapter of the list?

Comment: I declared it in the main class

`ArrayList<String> arrlst = new ArrayList<String>();`

Comment: do this way: get all call log first time. after that add each n every call(incoming, received, missed) in your list(using Broadcast receiver) or Database whatever you have used(So, no need to refresh call logs).

Comment: where are you using this arrlst list ?? in a list view ,if so you need to do this adapter.notifyDataSetChanged().This updates the values in list/grid view adapter

Comment: The arrlist is used to record what numbers are already used and prevents duplicates. Nothing else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `CursorLoader` to query a cursor containing the call log records. The `CursorLoader` will automatically refresh when the call logs are modified so you will not have to worry about refreshing the display manually (if you did need to refresh manually though, you can do so calling the `LoaderManager`'s `restartLoader()` method).

Comment: Could you give me a quick example of how I may use the cursorloader in this case? I was reading about it but I can't seem to understand how it full works.

Answer (score -1):

I actually got it to work with the following code

```
case (R.id.menuRefresh):
        allCalls = Uri.parse("content://call_log/calls");
        layout.removeAllViews();
        arrlst.clear();
        checkLogs();
```

Comment: You should accept this answer if it is the solution you are satisfied with. `CursorLoader` is definitely the recommended solution though... and it will make your code WAY simpler. Check out my [**blog posts**](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/07/loaders-and-loadermanager-background.html) on `Loader`s.

Comment: How do I query when using a CursorLoader?

I did the following
`clC.setUri(allCalls);`
  
`clC.setSortOrder(sOrder);`
  
`c = clC.loadInBackground();` where c is a cursor and cLc is a CursorLoader, but the app crashed when it called checkLogs on launch. Sorry if the question is straight forward, but I'm unable to find many resources to teach me about these loaders, they're new to me.

Comment: No, that's not how it works. You don't query the `CursorLoader` by calling its methods directly... you tell the `LoaderManager` to initialize the `CursorLoader` and the `LoaderManager` calls the `CursorLoader`'s methods instead (i.e. when it detects that new data is available). You should check out the [**documentation**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/LoaderManager.html) for the `LoaderManager`... there is also some sample code on my [**blog post**](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/07/understanding-loadermanager.html) illustrating the basic concept of how it works

Comment: So I followed the instructions in your blog, and implemented the LoadManager and set up the unimplemented methods. I made my onCreateLoader return `new CursorLoader(this, allCalls,
          null, null, null, sOrder);` and also made an mAdapter and added `getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);`. Instead of using `c = getContentResolver().query(allCalls, null, null, null, sOrder);` in my checkLogs method I used `c = mAdapter.getCursor();` and left the rest of the code the same other than removing the c.close() Am I doing something wrong with the cursor because it crashes. Added log above